# How to set-up a secondary/redundancy LTE internet connection?

Tags: internet, redundancy

We're a small-medium office in Vancouver Canada, and we're looking to set-up a secondary/redundancy LTE internet connection. We're looking at purchasing the Unifi Dream Machine Pro to solve this issue, however, I read in the catalog that the LTE secondary connection is available for the US only.
To overcome this, would using the Netgear NGLB1120 in conjunction with the UDM pro solve this issue?
Any recommendations for alternatives?

Also, would purchasing a sim card with an internet connection(for eg "Bring your own phone" plan) and using that sim in the Netgear be a viable source of secondary internet connection? or would I have to look for service providers who specifically offer secondary LTE internet connections?

Comment: (I do not know if the mentioned devices do the switching nicely) The sim choice might boil down to the contract terms you want (speed guarantees, outage reimbursement, ..). In any case, if the vendor selling the router or the LTE modem to be used in conjunction with the router tries to lock you in to a single mobile provider, that probably means you are paying extra for null benefits over common mobile phone contracts.

Comment: Save yourself a lot of headaches and start by shopping for a plan with your available LTE service providers.  You might even find an LTE fixed wireless plan available at a pretty good price.  Then ask that provider for a recommendation, or shop around, for equipment supporting that connection.  You definitely don't want to have your primary connection go down and then discover you purchased a consumer-grade LTE plan that throttles (or even blocks!) tethered connections.  (Full Disclosure: I'm a wireless core engineer at a large telecom provider)